# How do I access the assembly that is plist activated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

I am transitioning a project to use plist integration for Typhoon.  I can see that the assemblies that I added to the `TyphoonInitialAssemblies` key are being activated, but after I don't know how to access the activated assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the assemblies by injecting it/them. You can define a special case definition for the App Delegate, as [shown in the Typhoon example application](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon-example):

```
- (PFAppDelegate *)appDelegate
{
return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[PFAppDelegate class]     
    configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition)
    {
        //Inject the assembly
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(assembly)
            with:self];

        //Inject other properties
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(window)
            with:[self mainWindow]];
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(cityDao) 
            with:[_coreComponents cityDao]];            
    }];
}
```

. . or you can inject the assembly into any other Typhoon created component as well. This is useful from proceeding from one object graph to another with the [factory pattern](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Types%20of%20Injections#injection-with-run-time-arguments).

- Note that for the App Delegate (or other objects created outside of Typhoon) that property and method injection will work fine, but initializer injection is of course not supported. Also you can't down-scope an object, that is, a singleton created outside of Typhoon declared as a prototype, will remain a singleton.
- Also note that, if you wish, you can back your assemblies with a protocol, so that its not necessary to couple your classes directly to Typhoon.

The assembly bootstrapped via plist integration is also the one that is bound to your initial/main storyboard, so any [auto-injection](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Auto-injection-%28Objective-C%29) properties defined on your storyboard created view controllers will be fulfilled. This includes an assembly type property, eg:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) InjectedClass(MyAssembly) assembly;
```

The documentation for [this feature is here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself).

Comment: Thanks @Jasper!  Your work with Typhoon is great.  It truly is one of those frameworks that makes things feel *magical*.  One point of feedback is that I think there is a gap in the documentation and it might feel too magical.  I've read through every page on the wiki multiple times and have a basic understanding, but not the complete engineering understanding of how it works that is helpful in integrating it into legacy code or using it in new creative ways.  Perhaps more of a deep dive into implementation would be helpful? Just my $0.02. Thanks for your hard work!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @ScottH. Regarding the documentation, we'd love to provide a whole lot more. In fact I think there's a book's worth. http://appsquick.ly are still just a two person company from the quiet side of the world though, so I'm not sure how we're going to pull that off yet. . in the meantime I'd love to answer as many questions as you have. The implementation is fun: start with a strong foundation (a spring-like DI container) and use nice features of the Objective-C runtime (and concepts from aspect oriented programming) for the top interface.

Comment: @ScottH I corrected a bad typo that occurred during preparation of the answer. Regarding objects created outside of Typhoon, it was supposed to read "property and method injection *will work fine*, but initializer injection is of course not supported. . . "